# External Monitor does not run on full resolution with Mac.

Tags: mac

I bought a new Monitor which supports 1920 x 1080 Pixel and after connecting it to my Mac MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB I cant seem to get the full resolution.

Any idea how can I fix it?

[https://www.amazon.com/LG-32MA68HY-P-32-Inch-Monitor-Display/dp/B01IA9FXAO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IA9FXAO)

Comment: What kind of resolution are you expecting? What does the display control panel claim it's set to? Bear in mind that having a 32" 1080p monitor next to a retina, everything's going to look enormous & extremely fuzzy.

Comment: I'm running into this same problem too. Used a USB-C to DisplayPort cable without any luck and also tried a USB-C to multiport (DVI, VGA, HDMI) adapter.

Comment: @Yahoo Any updates on this?